# setInterval stopped when navigate to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added setInterval method for downloading one of data. But the intervel is cleared when navigated to next page? is the functionality is correct?

Regards,George

Comment: Yes, that's expected behaviour. If you want the interval to continue between requests you'll need to implement a single-page application architecture, which is not a simple task

Comment: When you change the page, the browser unloads all resources of the current page and then loads all the resources of the new page. So, you "loose" what you've done on the first page.

Comment: As the other comments say, yes, that's the intended behavior. You'll need to redeclare your `setInterval` on each page, unless it's a single page app which you navigate using a router.

Comment: Have you considered to use a Local Storage and access it from the other page? I think it would work, you can keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript variables (and setInterval generate a reference that you can save in a variable) are scoped by page.

Which means that when you are changing page, you make another request that reset your state.

Available solutions are the following :

- Avoid reloading the page and use AJAX to refresh your page, if you app is mostly rely on async data I suggests you using some frontend framework to make Single Page Application like React, Vuejs, Angular.
- You can also persist in localstorage or IndexedDB some data that can be given to a script that will run after page loading and create your interval.
- You might also take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: You should put a link to English documentation: you are pointing the french one.